# What am I missing to have 'move_up_down_links' display on 'ListAdmin' page using django-ordered-model?

Tags: python, django

I use `django-ordered-model==3.7.4` in my project to create an ordered model. I want to have a way to reorder list items via Django Admin.

I tried to use example code from `django-ordered-model`'s docs, but unfortunatelly it doesn't work as expected. Here's my code:

```py
# models.py
class ListItem(OrderedModel):
    """
    Represents an item of the user-created book list.
    """

    list = models.ForeignKey(
        verbose_name=_("список"),
        to=List,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name="items",
    )
    book = models.ForeignKey(
        verbose_name=_("книга"),
        to=Book,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name="list_items",
    )
    description = models.TextField(
        verbose_name=_("описание"),
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        default=None,
    )
    created = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name=_("создана"), auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name=_("изменена"), auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["order"]
        verbose_name = _("элемент списка")
        verbose_name_plural = _("элементы списков")
```

```py
# admin.py
class ListItemInline(OrderedTabularInline):
    model = ListItem
    fields = [
        "book",
        "description",
        "order",
        "move_up_down_links",
    ]
    readonly_fields = [
        "order",
        "move_up_down_links",
    ]
    ordering = [
        "order",
    ]
    extra = 0


@admin.register(List)
class ListAdmin(OrderedInlineModelAdminMixin, admin.ModelAdmin):
    """
    Configures admin views for List.
    """

    model = List
    list_display = [
        "title",
        "user",
        "is_public",
        "created",
    ]
    inlines = [ListItemInline]
    readonly_fields = [
        "created",
        "updated",
    ]


@admin.register(ListItem)
class ListItemAdmin(OrderedModelAdmin):
    """
    Configures admin views for ListItem.
    """

    model = ListItem
    list_display = [
        "book",
        "list",
        "order",
        "move_up_down_links",
        "created",
    ]
    readonly_fields = [
        "created",
        "updated",
    ]
```

As a result, I can see `move_up_down_links` on `ListItemAdmin` page:
[image]

But on the `ListAdmin` page, "Move" column is empty!
[image]

The question is - what I did wrong and how to display `move_up_down_links` on both pages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last, I solved the problem myself.

To make it work, I defined `move_up_down_links()` method in `ListItemInline` like this:

```py
    def move_up_down_links(self, obj):
        """
        Override `move_up_down_links` to properly show up/down links on `ListAdmin` page.
        """
        # `ListItem`'s "parent" object `pk` (`List` consists of `ListItem`'s).
        order_obj_name = str(obj.list.pk)
        model_info = self._get_model_info()

        name = "{admin_name}:{app}_{parent_model}_{model}_change_order_inline".format(
            admin_name=self.admin_site.name, **model_info
        )

        return render_to_string(
            "ordered_model/admin/order_controls.html",
            {
                "app_label": model_info["app"],
                "model_name": model_info["model"],
                "module_name": model_info["model"],  # backwards compat
                "object_id": obj.pk,
                "urls": {
                    "up": reverse(name, args=[order_obj_name, obj.pk, "up"]),
                    "down": reverse(name, args=[order_obj_name, obj.pk, "down"]),
                    "top": reverse(name, args=[order_obj_name, obj.pk, "top"]),
                    "bottom": reverse(name, args=[order_obj_name, obj.pk, "bottom"]),
                },
                "query_string": self.request_query_string,
            },
        )
```

Now all "up/down" links are displayed properly.

Answer (score 1):

How it is declared:
https://github.com/django-ordered-model/django-ordered-model#admin-integration

You should use `OrderedModelAdmin` class
In your case:

```
@admin.register(List)
class ListAdmin(OrderedModelAdmin):
    ...
```

The `OrderedInlineModelAdminMixin` dont work with `change_list` view in `ModelAdmin`. You can check it yourself: https://github.com/django-ordered-model/django-ordered-model/blob/master/ordered_model/admin.py

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I tried to update my code as you suggested, but up/down links did not appear...